# can I use bit coin to pay my overseas customers

Tags: money, money-transfer

I have a business where I have to pay customers on other countries , I want to have the ability to transfer my funds to a bank in another country with out having to pay the high bank fees for transferring funds

Comment: If I buy bit coin say in Australia , can I transfer from my bit coin to a bank account I own in Indonesia

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Bitcoin can be transferred peer to peer, to anyone over the net.

Now, you should note that:

- Bitcoin is very volatile.
- Bitcoin is very congested and slow these days, using litecoin or ethereum may be a better pick at the moment.

Also too, you will need to make sure your oversea customers will accept bitcoin payments. Some countries do not have a online exchange available to cash in bitcoins, so it is very important to tell your customers if bitcoin payments are ok.

tl;dr - yes, you can send bitcoin payments to anyone, in any country as long as they accept it. Then, your customer can optionally choose to cash it at a online exchange available to him for fiat cash.

Answer (score 0):

CASHAA (CAS) is designed to be the medium of payment for the millions of 'unbanked' in Asia & Africa . you can pay in tokens and the recipient can withdraw in their local fiat currency or credit to their bank account if they have one